# where are my seats on Air Canada 789

Tags: air-travel, air-canada

I have seats 6A and B where on the plane are they on Air Canada 789. Not sure where these seats are, as they were booked for me, does anyone know where they might be.

Comment: Based on the seat numbers alone I’d say near the front? All seats are numbered so are easy to locate, is there a particular reason you’re asking?

Comment: 6A and 6B are on the 6th row from the front, the two rightmost seats when you look towards the back (i.e. while boarding).

Comment: Do you mean the Boeing 787 Dreamliner 787-9, or Air Canada Flight 789?

Answer (score 2):

To make this potentially useful for other people, I'm interpenetrating your question as "how can I find a seat map of a specific flight".

Most airlines offer seat amps online on their web sites. A very good resource for this is also seatguru.com.

When you enter your information, make sure you are as specific and correct as possible. It's not unusual for airlines to use different aircraft for the same flight number on different dates either based on season or weekday.

Rows are numbered from the front to the rear with row number 1 being in the front. Within a row seats are lettered from left to right: A, B, C etc. Please note the rows and letters are not necessarily consecutive, i.e. some row numbers or seat letters may be missing depending on the layout and type of the specific aircraft

Comment: Note that the Air Canada seats are labelled A, B, C, right to left as you face the rear of the plane. I can't find a specific example now, but I have been on aircraft where the seats are labelled the other way (i.e. left-to-right as you face the rear of the plane)